# Fancybox hide button

Tags: button, fancybox, hide

My Fancybox is working so far, except for the close button which doesn't appear.

This is my Javascript:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();

     $('.single').fancybox({

     openEffect : 'elastic',
     closeEffect : 'none', 
     helpers : { 
     title : { 
     type : 'outside' } } 
     });
      });
```

I've tried working with the modal thingy but I don't know where I should put it, as I am new to Javascript.

Comment: More information needed to help you! There is nothing wrong with the above, but it's out of context. Provide the full script with references included.

Comment: what is the question : how to show the close button, which doesn't appear? -or- how to hide the close button?

Comment: I want to show the close button which isn't appearing right now, apparently it's not included in the Fancybox script so I don't know where I should put it.. http://jsfiddle.net/G3RQD

Comment: @Sophiaa : the `fancybox_sprite.png` (image) file, should be located on the same directory of the fancybox css file